# foreach loop execute once or execute each round

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a php code.

```
foreach($db->exec("SELECT * FROM users") as $k => $v) {
   # code ...
}
```

I want to know in the foreach loop, each round executes the `$db->exec("SELECT * FROM users")` code, or executes it once and uses it in each rounds?

I'm sorry if my english is bad :(

Comment: `exec` executed once.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your English is just fine, for the purposes of your question anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs as if it were this, running the query once then handling each row of the resultset.

```
$resultset = $db->exec("SELECT * FROM users");
foreach ( $resultset as $k => $v ) {
   # code ...
}
```

But, **beware**. You should always check for errors from external operations like DBMS queries. The way you wrote your code makes that hard. Here's a crude way to check for errors and stop your program if there are any

```
$resultset = $db->exec("SELECT * FROM users");
if (!$resultset) {
    print_r($db->errorInfo());
    die "sql error";
} 
else {
    foreach ( $resultset as $k => $v ) {
       # code ...
    }
}
```

If you're creating production-quality code you need to figure out a much better way of handling the error than I've shown: what I have will be rude to your users, not to mention give too much information to cybercreeps.